# Google Script Time-driven triggers not working

Tags: google-apps-script

I've tested successfully my script by running it manually. Today I've set up a time-driven trigger every day at 8.00am (GMT+07:00 Bangkok time zone) using the "current project's triggers" but the script didn't run.
I wonder what I am missing...

Comment: Can you paste some code of the function you're triggering?

Comment: Please provide minimal, complete and verifiable code, if you found any error please include. For the meantime, you may check this document regarding on how to create [time driven trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_programmatically).

Answer (score 1):

You can turn on execution failure notifications for your triggers. This will send you an email the day after your script triggers with the error message.